# how to instantiate ViewController from UIView in SWIFT

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to initialize view controller from my UiView. But i am getting error on the line self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) . I am trying to show another view controller after click on a table row. i have already initialized storyboard.

```
import UIKit

class CustomSwipeOut: UIView , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

    var label: UILabel = UILabel()
     var myNames = ["item1","item2","item3"]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addCustomView()   
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func addCustomView()
    {
       //add blank subview to the view
        var blankView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100))
        blankView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.addSubview(blankView)   

        //creating a tableview programmatically
        var tblView : UITableView = UITableView()
        tblView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 300, 200)
        self.addSubview(tblView)
        tblView.delegate = self
        tblView.dataSource = self
        tblView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")

    }

    //pragma mark- table view data source methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.myNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.myNames.count
    }

    //pragma mark - table view delegate methods

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            println("index o clicked")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MoneySum") as UIViewController
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        case 1:
            println("index 1 clicked")
        case 2:
            println("index 2 clicked")
        default:
            println("no index")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However..i accomplised using a delegate to pass an id from UIView to UIViewController and checking to the id i instantiated ViewController From UIViewController class as Para said in his answer . I did it as below

**Steps:**

**1) First create a protocol**

**2) create a Variable delegate conforming to protocol**

**3)Then create a call back method.**

```
//Step1:    
        protocol SendIndexDelegate{            
            func sendIndex(Int);            
        }

        class CustomSwipeView: UIView , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {      

            var delegate : SendIndexDelegate? //Step2           
            override init(frame: CGRect) {                
                super.init(frame: frame)
                self.addCustomView()                
            }
             ...... 

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {            
            var row = indexPath.row            
            //for optional binding            
            if let temp = self.delegate {                
                delegate?.sendIndex(row) //Step 3               
            }else{                
                println("optional value contains nill value")                
            }      
        }
    }
```

**Steps Continued for Another Class:**

**4) Conform to the protocol SendIndexDelegate(so method sendIndex(Int) must be impelemented by this class)**

**5) Assign the value self in variable delegate  in the optional variable delegate(it says that i will act as delegate for Class CustomSwipeView and implement the method sendIndex(Int))**

**6) Now implement the method and add body to it(because it has been delegate so must handle actions of the above class through call back method)**

```
    class RootViewController: UIViewController,SendIndexDelegate //Step4 {


            let rect: CGRect = CGRect (x: self.view.frame.size.width, y :10 , width: self.view.frame.size.width-50, height: self.view.frame.size.height-10)
            var a = CustomSwipeView(frame : rect)
            a.delegate = self//step5
            self.myView = a
            self.view.addSubview(self.myView)                
        }
   // Step 6:        
     func sendIndex(row : Int){

            switch row {

            case 0:                

                    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let moneySummaryVC: MoneySummaryVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("moneyVC") as! MoneySummaryVC
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(moneySummaryVC, animated: true)                 

            default:
                println("no index")                

            }      

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`presentViewController:animated:completion:` is a method defined only for `UIViewController`, not `UIView` ([see Apple doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)).

Your `UIView` is probably in the view hierarchy managed by a `UIViewController`.
A solution would be using a reference to that parent `UIViewController` and invoking `presentViewController:animated:completion:` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` to present any `ViewController` from your `UIView Class`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75396813/7385095