# Passing information from one UiView to Another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am beginning to learn Objective-c and my problem is the following:

I have created a UIView to create a profile and in that UIView, i have an imageView for the Picture as a Datepicker for the Birthday and a Slider for the Weight of the person. When the user presses the button "Conclude" i wish for him to have his Profile created and  show all the info that it was set before , Picture , Birthday,name and Weight there.

I tried to use prepareForSegue but i have no idea of what i am doing so could you guys give me a little hint on what i can do to make it work? thank you :)

Comment: Almost went out of breath trying to read this. Have you ever heard about period `. ` and paragraph?

Comment: From what I could understand here, it sounds like your best option might be to follow through a tutorial that does something similar to what you're trying to accomplish, then revisit your issue.  Try http://www.raywenderlich.com or similar sites for good tutorials.

Comment: you should use delegate to pass informatino from one UIVIew to another ViewController..but you have not mention where to pass it...use this insteads....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094106/how-to-instantiate-viewcontroller-from-uiview-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view controller you will be segueing to, you can setup variables to hold the information from the original view controller, then assign them in prepare for segue.

So in your destination view controller .h file, declare

`@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;` then in your prepare for segue in your original viewController

```
NextViewcontroller *nvc = [segue destinationViewController];
nvc.imageView = currentImageView;
```

You can access the imageView in the destination view controller by calling `self.imageView`