# From subview UIViewcontroller to other UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller, nib

My viewcontroller subview other viewcontroller and I Want to go to from that subview (ViewController) to other viewController. ? with segu o or open with nib any suggest ?

Controller1 has controller2 as subview and want to go to from controller2 to controller3

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094106/how-to-instantiate-viewcontroller-from-uiview-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `UIContainerView`, these are views that contain a view controller. Just try playing around with one by dragging it onto the Main.storyboard. You can make one visible and make the others visibility = false and visa versa.