# How can I call presentViewController in UIView class?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, presentviewcontroller

There is a custom tab in in my project that is on every screen of the app, so i made custom `UIView` class and `xib` file and added buttons in them. Now i want my buttons for navigations on different screens having different `story board` ids. But i can't call `presentViewController` from `UIView` class. Previously i custom function in `extension` class to navigate between screens but `UIView` class also can't call that function.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class tab: UIView {

var view: UIView!

@IBAction func btn1(sender: UIButton) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("6")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    xibSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { 
    super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
    xibSetup()
}

func xibSetup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib() 
    view.frame = bounds 
    view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight] 
    addSubview(view)
} 
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "tab", bundle: bundle) 
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    return view
} 
}
```

Comment: you might have to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094106/how-to-instantiate-viewcontroller-from-uiview-in-swift

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Call this function  on your button

```
func infoClick()  {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc: CampainDetailView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("campainDetailView") as! CampainDetailView
        let currentController = self.getCurrentViewController()
        currentController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
```

This  function will create root view controller

```
 func getCurrentViewController() -> UIViewController? {

    if let rootController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        var currentController: UIViewController! = rootController
        while( currentController.presentedViewController != nil ) {
            currentController = currentController.presentedViewController
        }
        return currentController
    }
    return nil

}
```

This above code must work, it is working for me in **Swift 4.0**

Comment: Thanks, it would look a little different in the latest swift versions when selecting the root view controller.

Answer (score 5):

You can use delegate. Add this to the Tab class

```
protocol TabDelegate {

    func didButtonTapped()
}

var delegate: TabDelegate?

@IBAction func btn1(sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didButtonTapped()
}
```

In the viewController where use the Tab.
Set the delegate like this

```
let tab = Tab()
tab.delegate = self
```

Then push the new viewController in the delegate method
And you can make a BaseViewController to do this, then all the viewController subClass it can have the same feature.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, TabDelegate {

    func didButtonTapped() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("6")
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

Class ViewControllerA: BaseViewController {
}

Class ViewControllerB: BaseViewController {
}
```

Comment: error at tab().delegate = self

cant not assign value of type "ViewController" to  type "TabDelegate?

Comment: plus i have this view in every controller so should i have to do this in every viewcontroller? isnt there any way to do it just once for all screens

Comment: Updated the answer.Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property  to this class, then your can use the methods of controller.

weak var controller:UIViewController!

self.controller?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: error is gone but still it's not navigating to that screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` to present any `ViewController` from your `UIView Class`.
In your `UIView` just write this line..

```
let yourViewController = UIViewController() // for example
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(yourViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Cheers!!